# UIImageview disappears while roating the device

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiimageview

I have added the UIImageview to the viewcontroller which was presented modally,my problem was when i rotate the device imageview disappearing.I am facing this problem in iPad when rotated in all orientation,but some time can able view the image.I was wondering with this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: mind sharing some code ?

Comment: Kunal i am just added the imageview in viewcontroller.While rotating image disappears.This is happening only for two orientation..The viewcontroller am presenting it modally..

Comment: I think your image is going out of screen bounds. You might want to check the frame coordinates of the imageview in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method of viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with Autolayout.  Ensure that you have your constraints set properly.  I.e. maybe set the distance of the top position to the superview and the leading position to the superview properly.

Comment: Thanks for you response...Sorry i doing it programatically..I just checked with auto layout ,but same result.